# Is it possible to fix OpenTimeout Exception?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-2.5

We have 2 REST Api applications written in Rails and .Net Framework 4.8. From the front-end we call rails api. For some services we call .Net REST API from Rails API project. .Net API project is deployed to test server.

Odd thing here is, I can get response for .Net Rest API endpoints if I consume them from postman. Whenever I try to call .Net Rest API endpoints from Rails API project, I'm getting OpenTimeout Exception. I tried setting up different timeouts for open-timeout, But I'm not getting why it throwing that error.

Others from my team has no such problem. I'm the only one facing that problem. I'm sure that the issue is from rails API project. But I couldn't find what it is.

Below is the CustomHttp Class we use to make Http requests.

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'
require 'json'

class CustomHttp
  VERB_MAP = {
    get: Net::HTTP::Get,
    post: Net::HTTP::Post,
    put: Net::HTTP::Put,
    delete: Net::HTTP::Delete,
    patch: Net::HTTP::Patch
  }.freeze

  def initialize(endpoint, token = '', client = nil, timeout = 240)
    @endpoint = endpoint
    @token = token
    @base_url = '' # .Net Web API base url
    @timeout = timeout
    @http = client.blank? ? http_client(@base_url) : client
  end

  def get(path, params)
    request_json :get, path, params
  end

  def post(path, params)
    request_json :post, path, params
  end

  private

  def http_client(base_url)
    use_ssl = base_url.to_s.downcase.include?('https')
    uri = URI.parse(base_url)
    http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
    http.use_ssl = use_ssl
    http.read_timeout = @timeout
    http
  end

  def request_json(method, path, params)
    response = request(method, path, params)
    body = JSON.parse(response.body, symbolize_names: true).with_indifferent_access

    {
      code: response.code,
      body: body,
      headers: response.instance_variable_get('@header')
    }.with_indifferent_access
  rescue JSON::ParserError => e
    exception_parser(e, response)
  rescue Timeout::Error => e
    exception_parser(e, response)
  rescue => e
    exception_parser(e, response)
  end

  def exception_parser(e, response)
    status_code = response.present? && response.code.to_i > 299 ? response.code.to_i : 500
    error_message = !response.respond_to?(:message) || response.message.blank? ? e.message : response.message
    {
      code: status_code,
      message: error_message,
      body: {success: false},
      headers: response.instance_variable_get('@header')
    }.with_indifferent_access
  end

  def encode_path_params(path, params)
    encoded = URI.encode_www_form(params)
    "#{path}?#{encoded}"
  end

  def add_authentication(request)
    req = request.clone
    req['Authorization'] = "Bearer #{@token}" unless @token.blank?
    req
  end

  def request(method, path, params = {})
    req = http_verb_for(method, params, path)
    final_req = add_authentication(req)
    @http.request(final_req)
  end

  def http_verb_for(method, params, path)
    case method
      when :get
        full_path = "#{@base_url}#{encode_path_params(path, params)}"
        req = VERB_MAP[method.to_sym].new(full_path)
      when :post_json
        full_path = "#{@base_url}#{path}"
        req = VERB_MAP[:post].new(full_path, 'Content-Type' => 'application/json')
        req.body = params.to_json
      else
        full_path = "#{@base_url}#{path}"
        req = VERB_MAP[method.to_sym].new(full_path)
        req.set_form_data(params)
    end
    req
  end
end
```

But, Below script worked.

```
require 'net/http'

AUTH_TOKEN = '' # place your auth token here

uri = URI.parse("Your endpoint to connect")
header = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': "Bearer #{AUTH_TOKEN}"}

http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri, header)
http.open_timeout = 10
response = http.request(request)
puts response.body
```

Don't know why I can't connect to the server from the rails API project.

We are using `rails 5.0.7`, `ruby-2.5.3` in macOs `Catalina`.
It'll be helpful If I can get a fix for this.

Comment: _"I'm the only one facing that problem"_ – do you mean it only happens on your machine and the same code runs fine on other machines?

Comment: Yes @Stefan. It is happening only in my machine.

Comment: @Stefan , I have wrote another ruby script to make an http request to one of the endpoints in .NET Rest API project. It worked fine. I'm guessing ruby is not the issue.

Comment: Is the other script using the same Ruby version and the same HTTP libraries?

Comment: Yes, @Stefan. Same.

Comment: If one script works fine and the other has timeouts, there must be a difference.

Comment: @Stefan I have edited question and added the script. You can take a look at it.